# "post offices can provide many of the same services OF banks"

Tags: grammar, sentence, parallelism

The diverse array of successful portal banking systems around the world shows that post offices can provide many of the same services **of banks**.

This sentence is incorrect, and "of banks" should be replaced by "provided by banks". Although I understand why "provided by banks" is a better sentence to maintain parallelism, why is the original sentence incorrect? I thought it was the most concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "same" takes the preposition "as" when used in this sense. "the same services of banks" is wrong.

The following are correct:

- post offices can provide many of the same services **as** banks.
- post offices can provide many of the services of banks.
- post offices can provide many of the services provided by banks.
- post offices can provide many of the services that banks do.